# WARNING: concurrent delete in progress within table while creating index in big table in Postgres 9.2

Tags: postgresql, concurrency

I have a problem while creating index on a big table which is 53 GB, so I tried to create this index  many times
the code is

```
do $$
begin
 if not exists (select * from pg_class where relname = 'index_usage_id_idx')       then
     create  index index_usage_id_idx on mytable (usage_id);
 end if; 
end $$;
```

I got many logs in pg_log directory with errors below  while creating index which does not stop and expose logs with more than 200 GB so that i am running out of free space

**2014-01-17 11:39:40  CONTEXT:  SQL statement "create  index index_usage_id_idx on mytable (usage_id)"

PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 46 at SQL statement

2014-01-17 11:39:40  WARNING:  concurrent delete in progress within table "mytable"**

Why is it trying to concurrent delete something?

Answer (score 0):

Another concurrent transaction is trying to delete rows from the table.

Either postpone these deletes somehow, by changing the application logic, or by creating a rule.

```
CREATE RULE
  _delete
AS ON
  delete
TO
  mytable
DO INSTEAD
  INSERT INTO my_table_to_be_deleted_later (...) VALUES (OLD...);
```

In that case you might need to drop FOREIGN KEY constraints as well (if my_table references another table or is being referenced) temporarily.

Or, just try to [CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY).

Comment: I have this exact error on a server without any other client. so this is not always related (if related at all, I don't see how it would be possible to create indexes on any busy server otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on a test server (8.4) without any other client running any query.

It *seems* that using the `concurrently` keyword for the create index solves the issue.

In your case:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY index_usage_id_idx ON mytable (usage_id);
```